# Session management in Spring Webflux WebFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Webflux and I handle the session in my web filters this way:

```
public class DemoFilter implements WebFilter {

      @Override
      public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, final WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {

           WebSession webSession = serverWebExchange.getSession().block();

           webSession.getAttributes().put("attribute", attributeValue);

           return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
      }
}
```

I wanted to remove that `block()` instruction and get the session in a non blocking way, so I tried this:

```
public class DemoFilter implements WebFilter {

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, final WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {

            return serverWebExchange.getSession()
                .doOnNext(webSession -> {
                webSession.getAttributes().put("attribute", attributeValue);
                }).then(webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange));
        }
}
```

Functionally, this code worked as the one above, but it seemed to cause the sessions not to close and accumulating when deployed on an testing environment (file descriptors alert).

Here's my project context: Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE, Tomcat, Webclient connection pool disabled (also causing sessions not closing).

Am I doing something wrong in this implementation? It is hard to find examples of WebFilters doing more than manipulating HTTP headers.

Comment: WebFlux is like a year old, still there is nearly no info at all...

Comment: Was there any solution to this?